# Link List Help, Iterator Issues

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

So I have to create a linked list for class and I am stuck with my `List::Current()` function. For some reason I'm getting a handling error when I try to call the function.

**List.h**

```
class List {
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;

        Node() : next(NULL){} //define our own default constructor
        Node(int data) : next(NULL), data(data){}
    };

    typedef struct Node* NodeRef;

    NodeRef head;
    NodeRef tail;
    NodeRef iterator; //points to one node at a time
    int size;

public:
    int current();
```

**List.cpp**

```
// initialize the values when they are instantiated
List::List() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), iterator(NULL), size(0) 
{}

int List::current() {
    return iterator->data;
}

void List::push_front(int data)             //Inserting a new node in     the front of the list
{
if (size == 0)                          //If there is no nodes in the        list, execute the if statement
{
    head = new Node(data);              //create a new node, and have head point to it
    iterator = tail = head;                     //have tail point to the new node also.

}
else                                    //If there are nodes in the list, execute the else statement
{
    NodeRef newNode = new Node(data);   //create a new node
    newNode->next = head;               //have the next pointer point to the head of the next node.
    head = newNode;                     //have the head pointer point to the new node inserted at the beginning of the list
}
size++;                                 //Increment the size counter

}

void List::push_back(int data)              //Inserting a node at the end of a list
{
if (size == 0)                          //If there are no nodes in the list, execute the if statement
{
    tail = new Node(data);              //Create a new node and have the tail pointer point to it.
    iterator = head = tail;                     //Have the head pointer point to the new node also.
}
else                                    //If there is atleast 1 node in the list, execute the else statement
{
    NodeRef newNode = new Node(data);   //Create a new node
    tail->next = newNode;               //Have the tail
    tail = newNode;                     //Have the tail pointer point to the new node.
    newNode->next = NULL;
}
size++;

}
void List::begin() //Set the iterator to the head of the list
{
iterator = head;
}

void List::scroll() //Allows us to scroll through the list
{
if (iterator == NULL)
    cout << "Iterator is pointing to null" << endl;
else
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    List B; //Create a new list

    B.push_front(5);
    B.push_front(4);
    B.push_front(3);
    B.push_back(10);

    cout << B.current() << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I left some code out because I didn't think listing the other functions that worked properly were necessary to get the point across. If you would like everything I could post that.

I think this solved my issues.

Comment: What sets iterator? If it is not set then it's either going to be 0 (in some compiler's debug build) or random, either of which will be undefined behaviour and not what you want.

Comment: Your class is incomplete, without a full example this question is pointless.

Comment: Ok, you've added the initialisation, but if you don't set it anywhere else then you will still get undefined behaviour when you access it.

Comment: @DominicMcdonnell, I think that is the issue I am having. Now my issue is, I don't quite understand where to have it set.

Comment: @JonnyHenly, the head is NULL in the list's constructor

Comment: @JonnyHenly, `NodeRef head;` -> `typedef struct Node* NodeRef;` -> `head(NULL)`. You can also see now in `push_front` it specifically sets head when there is no element.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell oh now I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you aren't setting iterator.

Personally I wouldn't include it as part of the class and have something like `begin()` or `head()` which retrieves an iterator class instance with the head pointer. Then the `current` and iteration methods would be a part of your iteration class.

But for your current design you could check in `push_front` to see if the iterator is NULL, and if so set it equal to head. Or you could have a `begin_iteration` method which sets it to the head, which would also allow you to do more than one iteration through the list.

**Edit**

Now that you have revealed your entire implementation, you need to set `iterator` in 2 places. At the end of `push_front`, and if there is no head in `push_back`. In other words anywhere you set `head`, you need to set iterator.

Also how do you move iterator forward? Can you restart the iteration?